# list stl вывод структуры

Tags: c++, stl, std-list

Прочесал интернет и не смог найти, как вывести все элементы структуры `list`.

Нашёл такой способ

```
copy(trD.begin(), trD.end(), ostream_iterator<bul>(cout, " "));
```

но он не пашет.

Может кто знает как вывести элементы структуры?

Структура

```
struct bul {
    char * name[3]; 
};
```

объект структуры `liststr`

```
list <bul> liststr;
```

Comment: вывести на экран?

Comment: Да вывести на экран.

Comment: Вопрос о том, что компилятор сам по себе не знает, как перевести в строку случайный пользовательский тип? И это интересный, полезный вопрос? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы использовать этот метод

```
std::copy( trD.begin(), trD.end(), std::ostream_iterator<bul>( std::cout, " ") );
```

вы должны определить оператор `operator <<` для вывода объекта типа `bul` в поток.

Иначе итератор `std::ostream_iterator<bul>` не будет иметь возможности вывести в поток объекты этой структуры.

Помимо использования алгоритма `std::copy` вы можете также использовать алгоритм `std::for_each`.

Но больший контроль над выводом вы будете иметь если будете использовать обычные циклы, как, например, `for` цикл, основанный на диапазоне

```
for ( const auto & item : trD )
{
    // вывод элементов структуры в желаемом формате
    // Например
    //  for ( char *n : item.name ) std::cout << n << ' ';
    //  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

или

```
for ( auto it = trD.begin(); it != trD.end(); ++it  )
{
    // вывод элементов структуры в желаемом формате
    // Например
    //  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) std::cout << it->name[i] << ' ';
    //  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Главная ваша задача - это определиться, как вы хотите выводить в поток объект вашей структуры. Либо вы напишите оператор `operator <<` для структуры, либо будете выводить в поток каждый ее член данных по отдельности.

Comment: По отдельности.

Comment: @IbragimMagomedov Как вам удобно. Тогда используйте один из показанных мной циклов и в тело цикла вставьте предложения, которые выводят члены структуры в том формате, какой вам требуется.

Comment: Можете пример привести вывода через 2 цикл?

Comment: @IbragimMagomedov Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: @IbragimMagomedov Не за что.